# Continuity under different metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

On the real line R define the standard Euclidean metric d(x,y)=|x-y| and e(x,y)=|arctan(x)-arctan(y)|. Show that: (i) A function f:R→R is continuous under d if and only if it is continuous under e;

Comment: I try to use mean value thm, 
 e(x_{n},x₀) = |arctan x_{n}-arctan x₀|
  = |((darctan(x))/(dx))|_{x=c}||x_{n}-x₀|
  = (1/(1+c²))|x_{n}-x₀|

Comment: But only can get one side

Comment: I would recommend that you edit your question and tell everyone that you already have one side. Then others shall be happy to help you with the other direction. Also this will show that you have put some thoughts, and will help others to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the usual open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are generated by either $d$ or $e$. That is, $U$ is open with $d$ **iff** $U$ is open with $e$.

Continuity follows from this.